# would someone with fire abilities run hot or cold?

Tags: magic

In the world that I am creating, there are various elf types. One of the types are sun elves. Their abilities range from controlling light beams to conjuring fire. In general, they deal with fire, light, and/or heat. They could either run hot or cold, however I haven’t decided which.

They could run hot, and be warm to the touch, because of their heat inside. The inner warmth from their abilities may transfer throughout their bodies, making them hot to the touch.

They could also run cold, to equalize the warmth within. All the heat from their magic would need to be toned down, or else their body temperature would be way too hot. In order to keep their bodies a healthy temperature, their bodies would need to be cooler to equalize the heat.

Honestly, both would work. Anyone have thoughts on whether they would run hot or cold?

Comment: [tag:science-based] and [tag:magic] used together? That's odd, but not entirely impossible. Can you explain the nature of your magic system? Specifically where is the "energy" to perform "work" coming from? How is it channeled through the body? What are its limits? The more detail you can give us, the better this will be. To give you a [tag:science-based] answer we need to know the fundamentals of how your [tag:magic] works.

Comment: how are we supposed to tell you how your magic system works?

Comment: We can't easily explain your magic for you. We might be able to help you refine it, but you need to define the rules of your magic before anyone can help you figure out side effects and implications and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely answer is that they run both hot and cold.

As explained in the comment to causative, a flamethrower runs hot due to the inefficiencies causing some heat to end up in the weapon itself. A freezer takes the internal heat and expells in outside. Since its magic there is another option for the freezer type method: it expells heat from the surroundings of the caster rather than the bodyheat (although bodyheat could be included).

If your caster uses the first freezer method his mana will be the catalist to shift heat and his casting is limited. He'll use up his body heat, which is in limited supply. Even more limited due to the risk of undercooling.

If your caster uses the flamethrower method his mana will be "burned" to create the spell and heat. This also has its limits as the caster will quickly heat up and suffer heatstrokes.

If the caster uses the second freezer method it depends on the environment how many spells he can cast. Near hot springs, deserts and bonfires his spellcasting is near endless, in a cold environment it will have many more limitations as more energy will be subtracted from high energy sources like the caster. It would be logical that in cold environments more mana is required to subtract the heat energy to power the spell. This can also have effects like putting out the campfire before much energy is taken from other sources nearby, which could in turn have effects on the amount of mana required.

The best solution is to use all options. Some spells heat up the body, some spells can be used to expell the extra body heat, some spells draw from the environment but at a higher mana cost the farther the source is and the less energy it has. You can even allow all spells to do all 3, but the method of casting differs depending on which version you use. This is also an excellent downside to the casting, as the caster constantly has to be aware of his environment and body heat.

Comment: What I find interesting in your idea is also that it can be arbitrarily limited to allow only one or 2 of the types, making some environments natural threats to those spell users.

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish to be scientifically accurate (specially given the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) tag)?

If they "run cold" permanently due to their spells, it makes them slower. If it's just a couple degrees (in C) (and e.g.: like a platypus, when compared to other mammals) the difference might not be perceptible, but in any case they would have lower metabolism. They would need less food per body weight, but would also be slower.

If they only run cold when they cast, well... they'll become slow when they cast. Might be a vulnerability.

If they run hot permanently, they beed more food and would be comparatively more active. If they run hot when they cast, they might need to have a metabolism like that of a bat. Bats have many adaptations to keep cool as they fly, [including having lost all genes for inflammatory reactions](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fimmu.2020.00026/full) - which is why they can harbor so many deadly viruses, such as the ones for rabies, with impunity. They still might need to cast cautiously so as not to overheat and die.

Answer (score 1):

Does a flamethrower run hot, or cold?

Does a furnace run hot, or cold?

If you go for a run, do you get hot, or cold?

Machinery of any kind generally runs hot, unless it has a specialized way of cooling part of itself down, such as a freezer.  (Even so, a standing freezer heats the room it is in).

A fire mage with normal human biology would need a way of maintaining a normal body temperature within a couple degrees.  They can sweat a lot, or their magic doesn't get hot until it's outside of them.  Or they have ice magic as well to cool themselves.

If you want them to be "naturally" cold, then perhaps you can say that mana is drawn from some external plane and is naturally very cold, like liquid oxygen.  So it doesn't get hot until you combine it with liquid hydrogen and add a spark, outside your body.

Comment: I think that is the crux of the question here: is it like a flamethrower, where a part of the energy released heats up the weapon itself, or is it a freezer, where energy from the inside/body is expelled outside? Considering its magic it depends: is the mana the fuel which "burns" and causes inefficiencies or does the mana shift body heat to the outside? This then gives you the answer: body heat is a much more limited supply compared to a more nebulous mana capacity, so you would expect heat to be generated. Science-based at its core, using the magic as far as explained.